# Is there any command in linux which will force linux machine to not shut-down

Tags: linux, command-line, shutdown

I have a very important process which is having a Queue, In Queue i'm storing important data and when if someone trap that process it must have to process the data which is there in the Queue after that it will terminate itself.

So if user perform a shut-down operation then that process will be killed and my data will be lossed...

So my Question is, Do we have any command which will wait or do not allow machine to shut-down, Or give your valuable alternative suggestion for handling this situation.

Comment: Store the queue data on a permanent medium (file(s)) and process individual elements from there. Even if you block the system from shutdown, you'll never going to prevent someone from pulling the plug.

Comment: So what happens with those logs coming in when the system is (going) down? Whether they come from the system itself or not, if processing via a permanent medium is a problem, you are going to drop data unless you can stop the log creating in the first place.

Comment: they are not coming directly I am reading few of them and keeping in my queue my queue size is of size 10000, I increased to improve the performance if previously it was at 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your software do a critical job you have to write a service file and put it under `/etc/init.d` that when computer goes down your script start `stop` function in that script which you need to clean up to not mess up your program. Like Oracle DB that when system goes down it will close ports to don't transaction any information and then save the information on the hard disk (Clean Up!).

**NOTE:** Good software clean up data itself after the `stop` function in service file sends specific signal (Mostly 15).

**NOTE:** Normal users can't execute shutdown procedure with commands like `reboot -p` or `shutdown -h now` or `init 0`.

**NOTE:** Normal users can't kill process which owned by root.